# Amazon wishlist shows my basic address

Tags: amazon, wish-list

I've made a wishlist on Amazon but when using the "show my wishlist as seen by others" feature, I get to see my own address. Not only that, it also shows my name and last name. My real name is not an issue, but I don't want my last name and address to be shown to the public. Ideally I wouldn't want anyone to see it, but I could understand if a purchaser/donor could see it *after* buying something for me.

I've tried looking into the options but there is nothing that actually sets the address or other personal information as private.

If it matters, I'm speaking about Amazon.it, but I guess the options are the same across the per-nation domains.

Comment: Have you tried it from someone else's computer, or after logging out?  Sometimes "public" pages still show personal info to the owner of that info.

Comment: @techturtle Yes, I've asked someone else to visit the link to my wishlist, they see the same.

Answer (score 1):

On the left, click "Show list profile", then a new section will appear below. Click "Update this list's profile". There you can change your name to not include your last name.

You can also remove the address entirely, which will require anyone purchasing something off the list to enter your address. (Though, it should never display the entire address, only name & city.) If its showing more than name & city, either Amazon.it is different than Amazon.com or maybe your shipping address is entered some weird way (e.g., entire thing in the city field).

Comment: This doesn't change anything to me... It says "List of..." and my name, ok, but below that there's a "Sent this to:..." with full name, city and province. And I cannot change that without removing the address completely (which defeats the purpose of the wishlist for me in a way). I would prefer only the first name to be displayed, no last name or city at all. I seem to remember this was possible.

Comment: @Alenanno That full name is part of the address you put on the list—the form prompts you for full name, but you can put only your first name in there. I don't think there is a way to hide the address info entirely, except by having none.

Comment: @Alenanno Is this Q/A still relevant? I just realized my wishlist was public, but didn't see my address.

Comment: @Louis no idea if Amazon has changed something.